# Moving a table from a database to another - Only insert missing rows

Tags: postgresql

I have two databases that are alike, one called `datastore` and the other called `datarestore`.

`datarestore` is a copy of `datastore` which was created from a backup image. The problem is that I accidentally deleted a little too much data from `datastore`.

Both databases are located on different AWS instances and I typically connect to them using `pgAdmin III` or Python to create scripts that handle the data.

I want to get the rows that I accidentally deleted from `datastore` which are in `datarestore` into `datastore`. Does anyone have any idea of how this can be achieved. Both databases contain close to 1.000.000.000 rows and are on version 9.6.

I have seen some backup/import/restore options within `pgAdmin III`, I just don't know how they work and if they support my needs? I also thought about creating a python script, but querying my database has become pretty slow, so this seems not to be an option either.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id (serial - auto incrementing int) | - primary key
| did (varchar) |
| sensorid (int) |
| timestamp (bigint) |
| data (json) | 
| db_timestamp (bigint) |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You can look at [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/). Not sure about `1.000.000.000` rows, performance etc. In any case it's better to do the test.

Comment: You can backup and restore from a single table or tables from which you deleted data. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html To get just the rows you deleted you would need to PIT (point in time) recovery. The dump option may be the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you preserved primary keys between those databases then you could [create foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) pointing from `datarestore` to `datastore` and check what keys are missing (using for example `select pk from old_table except select pk from new_table`) and fetch those missing rows using the same foreign table you created. This should limit your first check for missing PK to just index only scans (+ network transfer) and then it will be index scan to fetch missing data. If you are missing only small part of it then it shouldn't take long.

If you require more detailed example then I'll update my answer.

EDIT:

### Example of foreign table/server usage

Those commands need to be exuecuted on `datarestore` (or `datastore` if you choose to push data instead of pulling it).

If you don't have foreign data wrapper "installed" yet:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
```

This will create virtual server on your `datarestore` host. It is just some metadata pointing at foreign server:

```
CREATE SERVER foreign_datastore FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host 'foreign_hostname', dbname 'foreign_database_name',
         port '5432_or_whatever_you_have_on_datastore_host');
```

This will tell your `datarestore` host what user should it connect as when using fdw on server `foreign_datastore`. It will be used only for `your_local_role_name` logged in on `datarestore`:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR your_local_role_name SERVER foreign_datastore 
OPTIONS (user 'foreign_username', password 'foreign_password');
```

You need to create schema on `datarestore`. It is where new foreign tables will be created.

```
CREATE SCHEMA schema_where_foreign_tables_will_be_created;
```

This will log in to remote host and create foreign tables on `datarestore`, pointing to tables at `datastore`. ONLY tables will be done this way.
No data will be copied, just structure of tables.

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA foreign_datastore_schema_name_goes_here
  FROM SERVER foreign_datastore INTO schema_where_foreign_tables_will_be_created;
```

This will return list of `id` that are missing in your datarestore database for this table

```
SELECT id FROM foreign_datastore_schema_name_goes_here.table_a
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM datarestore_schema.table_a
```

You can either store them in temp table (`CREATE TABLE table_a_missing_pk AS [query from above here]`
Or use them right away:

```
INSERT INTO datarestore_schema.table_a (id, did, sensorid, timestamp, data, db_timestamp)
SELECT id, did, sensorid, timestamp, data, db_timestamp
  FROM foreign_datastore_schema_name_goes_here.table_a
 WHERE id = ANY((
   SELECT array_agg(id)
     FROM (
       SELECT id FROM foreign_datastore_schema_name_goes_here.table_a
       EXCEPT
       SELECT id FROM datarestore_schema.table_a
     ) sub
  )::int[])
```

From my tests, this should push-down (meaning send to remote host) something like that:

```
Remote SQL: SELECT id, did, sensorid, timestamp, data, db_timestamp
FROM foreign_datastore_schema_name_goes_here.table_a WHERE ((id = ANY ($1::integer[])))
```

You can make sure it does by running `explain verbose` on your full query to see what plan it will execute. You should see `Remote SQL` in there.

In case it does not work as expected, you can instead create temp table as mentioned earlier and make sure that this temp table is on `datastore` host.

Alternative approach would be to create foreign server on `datastore` pointing to `datarestore` and push data from your old database to new one (you can insert into foreign tables). This way you won't have to worry about list of `id` not being pushed down to `datastore` and instead fetching all data and filtering them afterwards (with would be extremely slow).

Comment: The primary keys are preserved. So this should be doable. A more detailed answer would be appreciated. I'll update my question, with the structure of my table. I guess I should make sure that you know that the two tables (`datastore` and `datarestore`) are located on different databases/hosts. Is it still doable?

Comment: Hey, sorry I updated it this late, I was just finishing my work and that is why I gave short answer. It is now updated with example of fdw usage.
As for your question about different hosts between `datastore` and `datarestore` - it won't be a problem, because fdw is mostly used for connecting to remote hosts. Unless of course firewall prevents connections.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the reply. I will get onto trying to make it work ;)

Comment: Just to be sure. The above commands (to be executed on `datarestore`) will  push data from my `datarestore` to my `datastore`?

Comment: Yes and no. It will pull list of `id` from `datastore` and compare it vs what you have on `datarestore` (`select id from [..] except select id from [..]`), so it pulls data here. Then it will push that list down to `datastore` so that it knows what rows to transfer from `datastore`. Ideally `datastore` at this point will only transfer rows that are missing and no additional filtering will be done on `datarestore`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Maybe it would be actually better to create foreign tables on your `datastore` instead (my last point of answer). Then you have one less network transfer, since you 1. take `id` from `datarestore` 2. send filtered rows to `datarestore` instead of 3 data transfers involved with my solution (I didn't think it thru initially).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154310/discussion-between-zeliax-and-lukasz-kaminski).

Comment: After having reformatted the code this ended up being exactly what I needed. I will add a small edit once I have time to show exactly what I ended up doing in details for someone else to find in the future. Thanks for the help @Łukasz Kamiński!